# SQL Server user-defined function return nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query is written for SQL Server and if I hard code `@TempStaff` then it works fine and there is a value in `@Tempstaff` but the code like this does not return anything.

The query is to collect all employees at the staffs level and below:

```
DECLARE 
    @TempStaff  varchar(10),
    @staff_Full_name varchar (30)   
BEGIN
SELECT @staff_Full_name = 'Doe, John'
DECLARE @staffNameTable TABLE
    (
    StaffID     char(7),
    StaffName   Varchar(50)
    )
INSERT INTO @staffNameTable
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_Staff_Full_Name()

SELECT  @TempStaff =    (
                SELECT  StaffId
                FROM    @staffNameTable st
                WHERE   st.StaffName = @staff_Full_name 
                )
END 
DECLARE @staff  TABLE
            (
    StaffId char(10)
    )

INSERT INTO @staff (StaffId)
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_Supervisor_List(10, @TempStaff)`
```

The function is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Supervisor_List] 
(
    @looptill   Int,
    @StaffId    varchar(10)
)
RETURNS 
@staff  TABLE
    (
    StaffId char(10)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @loop       int 

    INSERT  INTO    @staff
    SELECT  s.StaffId
    FROM    Staff s with (nolock)
    WHERE   s.StaffId like @StaffId

    BEGIN
        SELECT  @loop = 0

        WHILE   @loop < @looptill 
        BEGIN

            INSERT  INTO    @staff
            SELECT  s.StaffId
            FROM    dbo.StaffSupervisors s with (nolock)
            --WHERE s.super_id in   (
            WHERE   s.SupervisorId in   (
                        SELECT  s2.StaffId
                        FROM    @Staff s2
                        )
            AND s.StaffId not in    (
                            SELECT  s2.StaffId
                            FROM    @Staff s2
                            )
            SELECT  @loop = @loop + 1
        END
    END
    RETURN 
END
```

When I run SELECT @TempStaff after filling it - I get the variable that I would expect but when I run SELECT * FROM @Staff at the end @Staff is empty.

Comment: Have you tried printing out @TempStaff right after you select a value into it? Do you get the expected output?

Comment: You can [debug UDF's in Visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165047(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Any reason you've written this loop and not just used a CTE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the problem, I had declared the Value @TempStaff to be a Varchar but when I changed it to INT then it worked fine.  Thank you everyone that posted with suggestions.  I will certainly be looking into CTE's.